# "Pas franchement" vs "franchement pas"

Tags: sens, adverbes, ordre-des-mots

> Tu n'as **pas franchement** l’air d’être si occupée que ça...

I wonder if "pas franchement" is close in meaning to "***pas tout à fait / pas vraiment / not quite***"?

> {vs}: Tu n'as **franchement pas** l’air d’être si occupée que ça...

... whereas with the word order of "franchement pas", "franchement" has the meaning of "***pour être honnête***"? Or is it more like "***absolument pas***"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Tu n'as pas franchement l’air d’être si occupée que ça...

Is "pas vraiment", as you said => "pas tout à fait"

Here "pas" moderates "franchement".

> {vs}: Tu n'as franchement pas l’air d’être si occupée que ça...

Is "vraiment pas" => "absolument pas"

Here "franchement" emphasis "pas" (so comparable to "absolument pas").

Surely comparable to "not truly" and "truly not"... (?)

**Edit**: in complement, if you want to mean "pour être honnête", that can be:

> Franchement, tu n'as pas l'air d'être si occupée que ça..."